# Multithreading or Multiprocessing for a webautomation bot in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, multiprocessing, webautomation

My script scans the price of certain products on nike.com and will keep scraping the price of the products till it goes on sale and at that point it will create multiple instances to login into multiple accounts to purchase the product.

I already have the function of scraping the website and checking out the product made but I want to know should I use multiprocessing or multithreading to execute the logging in and checking out process?

Which will be more efficient at handling multiple instances of the web-automation process? I'm using selenium headless in firefox if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are much faster to create, have a smaller memory footprint since they share memory and can communicate by just updating variables, since they all have access to the same memory space.

I personally like to you the `multiprocessing.dummy` module that let's you handle threads with the multiprocessing api which is very handy.

Comment: I dont get your argument: since selenium will start on a new process, go ahead and start one yourself too because why not? Also OP said he wants to login. What kind of password do you think hes keeping in memory so that a memory limit could be reached? I just don't get your argument